# In RDS digest function is undefined after creating pgcrypto extension

Tags: amazon-rds, aws, pgcrypto

On an AWS RDS instance, we have run

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
```

The extension gets created.  Both queries:

```
SELECT digest('a', 'sha256') FROM table_name;
SELECT public.digest('a', 'sha256') FROM table_name;
```

Gives the error **function public.digest(unknown, unknown) does not exist**

Comment: Can you show the output of `\df digest` in `psql`, please?

Answer (score 5):

My coworker discovered the issue, in case anyone is having a similar problem, the issue was that pgcrypto had been installed into a schema that was not public.  So the query for reported installed extensions said it was installed, installing if not exists did not change its schema or install it to all schemas.  The final solution was to remove it from all schemas and install it directly in the public schema.

Comment: In my case I've removed the extension when no schema selected and added it again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311405/aws-rds-postgres-crypto-functions-doesnt-work-even-with-the-pgcrypto-extension